# How do you "condense" long recursive Polars expressions?

Tags: python, python-polars

The Polars expression language is amazing, but it very occasionally can cause issues when the expression definition becomes extremely large.

In my experience this only happens with recursion - for example:

```py
def diffuse(c:pl.Expr, n_time_steps=1, conductivity:float=0.05)->pl.Expr:
    '''Applies a heat-equation inspired smoothing to a time series of values'''
    
    c_conductivity=(1-conductivity)
    
    new_c = c
    for _ in range(n_time_steps):
        new_c = (c_conductivity*new_c) + (0.5*conductivity*(new_c.shift(-1).forward_fill() + new_c.shift(1).backward_fill()))
        
    return new_c
```

With `n_time_steps > 10` the `diffuse` function can easily return a multi-gigabyte expression.

One mitigation to this is to apply the function in "chunks" - it seems to work:

```py
df = (df
       .with_columns(__temp__ = pl.col('heat'))
       .with_columns(__temp__ = pl.col('__temp__ ').pipe(diffuse, n_time_steps = 5)) # Equivalent to pl.col('heat').pipe(diffuse, n_time_steps=5) 
       .with_columns(__temp__ = pl.col('__temp__ ').pipe(diffuse, n_time_steps = 5)) # Equivalent to pl.col('heat').pipe(diffuse, n_time_steps=10)
       .with_columns(__temp__ = pl.col('__temp__ ').pipe(diffuse, n_time_steps = 5)) # Equivalent to pl.col('heat').pipe(diffuse, n_time_steps=15)
       .with_columns(__temp__ = pl.col('__temp__ ').pipe(diffuse, n_time_steps = 5)) # Equivalent to pl.col('heat').pipe(diffuse, n_time_steps=20)
       .rename({'__temp__':'heat[diffused with n_time_steps=20]'})
)
```

However, I suspect I'm missing some Polars functionality that would handle this situation better.

To clarify, I am trying to keep this as a function that takes in a `pl.Expr` and returns a `pl.Expr` - otwise the above could be implemented as a `pl.DataFrame` to `pl.DataFrame` function:

```
def add_diffused_column(
        df:pl.DataFrame, 
        col:str, 
        n_time_steps=1, 
        conductivity:float=0.05
    )->pl.DataFrame:

    dummy_column_name = f'__dummy_column_{np.random.rand()}'
    assert dummy_column_name not in df.columns, 'By chance the dummy column name already exists in the dataframe :('

    df = df.with_columns(pl.col(col).alias(dummy_column_name))

    for i in range(n_time_steps)
        df = df.with_columns(pl.col(dummy_column_name).pipe(diffuse, n_time_steps=1, conductivity=conductivity)

    return df.rename({dummy_column_name: f'{col}[iffused with n_time_steps={n_time_steps}]'})

df.pipe(add_diffused_column, 'heat', n_time_steps=100)
```

Comment: You could do the latter `__temp__` assignments in a loop instead of unrolling the loop yourself.

Comment: I could, but in either case this turns my operation into a `pl.DataFrame -> pl.DataFrame` function when what I want to implement is a `pl.Expr -> pl.Expr` function.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this at just the `Expr` level. Justy trying to print the query plan of your `n_time_steps=10` example segfaults for me: `df.lazy().with_columns(pl.col("heat").pipe(diffuse, n_time_steps=10)).explain()`

Comment: Looking at the Rust implementation, it's clear that `df.with_columns` creates a _new_ logical plan, with various optimizations and whatnot, whereas operations on expressions just create more and more deeply nested enums. Since I don't think Python has access to the logical plans, I think you just have to go through the df.

Comment: @BallpointBen numba works...see answer.

Answer (score 2):

polars doesn't have recursion built in except for a few cumulative and rolling type functions.

You have two options, one is to write your `diffuse` in rust using the [pyo3 adapter](https://github.com/pola-rs/pyo3-polars)

The other is to write it with [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/vectorize.html#the-guvectorize-decorator) and compile it as a [ufunc which polars supports](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/user-guide/expressions/numpy/)

Here's a numba example:

```
import polars as pl
import numpy as np
import numba as nb



@nb.guvectorize([(nb.float64[:], nb.float64, nb.float64[:])],'(n),()->(n)', nopython=True)
def diffuse_ufunc(data, conductivity, res):
    c_conductivity=(1-conductivity)
    for i in range(len(data)):
        prev_i=max(0,i-1)
        next_i=min(i+1,len(data)-1)
        res[i] = c_conductivity*data[i] + 0.5 * conductivity * data[prev_i] + 0.5 * conductivity * data[next_i]


def diff_expr(c, n_time_steps=1, conductivity=0.05)->pl.Expr:
    if isinstance(c, str):
        c=pl.col(c)
    new_c = c
    for _ in range(n_time_steps):
        new_c = diffuse_ufunc(new_c, conductivity)
        
    return new_c
```

with that you can do

```
df=pl.DataFrame({'heat':np.random.normal(10,2,1000)})
df.with_columns(a15=diff_expr('heat',15,0.05))
## or, as I prefer
# monkey patch it to pl.Expr (one time only)
pl.Expr.diffuse=diff_expr
# then using it is more polarsish
df.with_columns(a15=pl.col('heat').diffuse(15,0.05))
```

For me it returns pretty much instantly and doesn't move the RAM usage in htop by a noticeable amount (basically not at all). In contrast when I did the same with your `diffuse` it used many GBs of RAM before I interrupted it after about 20 seconds. I think it's all for forward and backward fills which get exponentially bigger. Putting that logic in the ufunc forces it to compute it for each loop.

## Do step looping in numba function

I couldn't get this to work on my first attempt but now it's working in this form

```
@nb.guvectorize([(nb.float64[:], nb.int32, nb.float64, nb.float64[:])],'(n),(),()->(n)', nopython=True)
def diffuse_ufunc2(_data, n_time_steps, conductivity, res):
    c_conductivity=(1-conductivity)
    _temp=_data.copy()
    for step in range(n_time_steps):
        for i in range(len(_data)):
            prev_i=max(0,i-1)
            next_i=min(i+1,len(_data)-1)
            res[i] = c_conductivity*_temp[i] + 0.5 * conductivity * _temp[prev_i] + 0.5 * conductivity * _temp[next_i]
        if step<n_time_steps-1:
            _temp=res.copy()
```

I think the issue I was having was changing _data between each loop which, for some reason, was making it give different results for steps>1. Additionally, I wasn't copying res from step to step but by taking care of those now it works.

Now doing `%%timeit` gives

```
df.with_columns(b15=diffuse_ufunc2(pl.col('heat'),15,0.05))
446 µs ± 60.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Compared to

```
df.with_columns(b15=diff_expr(pl.col('heat'),15,0.05))
5.57 ms ± 677 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

A 12x improvement for n=15.

One note, ufuncs can't have optional or default parameters but you can still wrap it in a helper function that does have them if you prefer.

Comment: Ohh, exciting - this is new to me. And yes, the forward and backward fills are not computationally ideal, but they serve a purpose.

Comment: Excellent - it seems to be 13x faster than the dataframe implementation (with steps of 1). That said, it's not currently playing nice with the `.over()` method of pl.Expr - but I'll look into it.

Comment: Worked via `df.group_by('sampleId').map_groups(lambda df: df.with_columns(heatDiffused = pl.col('heat').pipe(diff_expr, n_time_steps=90)))` though now it's "only" 2x faster than the previous implementation (still amazing!).

Comment: I put in a big speed improvement especially for n=90

Comment: Awesome. Do you know a way to get ".over" working with ufuncs? Or is the code from my comment more or less what you would do?

Comment: This *just* works for me `df.with_columns(a=diffuse_ufunc2(pl.col('heat'), 15, 0.05).over('sampleId'))`. My sampleId is just a random integer between 1 and 5.

Comment: I think this will work in `over` or `group_by` now. The ufunc internally calls `map_batches` which previously had the behavior of ignoring groups and giving the same answer as if there were no group (which you already noticed). With this [PR](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/13181) that behavior was changed which corresponds to version 0.20.3

Comment: Awesome - I had parked this for given the issue, I'll revisit it now